# WooCommerce: disable AJAX reload on product page when selecting an attribute

Tags: woocommerce, storefront

in WooCommerce 4.2.0, when the user selects an attribute on the product page (i.e. product size), the AJAX reloads the "other products" in WooCommerce tabs. It's painful for the user to wait for this. How to disable this AJAX reload please ?

[image: See the reload on the picture and the whole page is greyed out]

The code for the "other colors" tabs in my Storefront child-theme's functions.php:

```
/*ADD custom "other colors" tab */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'wpb_new_product_tab_othercolors' );
function wpb_new_product_tab_othercolors( $tabs ) {
    // Add the new tab
    global $post;
    $othercolorsbool = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_othercolorsbool', true );
    // var_dump('$othercolorsbool :');
    // var_dump($othercolorsbool);
    if ( $othercolorsbool === "false" || $othercolorsbool === "" || $othercolorsbool === "0" ) {
        unset( $tabs['othercolors_tab'] );
        return $tabs;
    } else {
        if( get_locale() == 'fr_FR' ) {
            $tabs['othercolors_tab'] = array(
                'title'       => __( 'AUTRES COULEURS', 'text-domain' ),
                'priority'    => 0,
                'callback'    => 'wpb_new_product_tab_content_othercolors'
            );
        } else {
            $tabs['othercolors_tab'] = array(
                'title'       => __( 'OTHER COLORS', 'text-domain' ),
                'priority'    => 0,
                'callback'    => 'wpb_new_product_tab_content_othercolors'
            );
        }
        return $tabs;
    }
}
function wpb_new_product_tab_content_othercolors() {
    
    global $post;
    $title = $post->post_title;

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
        break;
    }

    $splitted = product_name_split($title);
    $productname = $splitted[0];
    $productcolor = $splitted[1];

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $product_cat_id
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $product_cat_id
            )
        ),
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby' => 'title',
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    $r = 0;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $r = $r + 1;
        $the_query->the_post();
        $currenttitle = get_the_title();

        if ( strpos($currenttitle, $productname) !== false) { //if iteration product has the same name as the productname, then find its color: $productcolorbis

            $splitted = product_name_split($currenttitle);
            $productnamebis = $splitted[0];
            $productcolorbis = $splitted[1];

            if ( ($productcolorbis !== $productcolor) ) { //if iteration product color is different than productcolor, then go
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            }
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: `return false;` in callback `wpb_new_product_tab_content_othercolors` function, and it empty the results.

Comment: I don't want to empty the results! I want them not to update when I click a an attribute.

Comment: then you need to find the `JS` code and post it here, not `PHP`, from JS code you disable the `AJAX` call.

Comment: Is there an option in woocommerce or something to take over in functions.php ? any idea @loictheaztec ?